# Readline is not readig the first line

Tags: combobox, text-files, line

My code is not reading the first line of my text file. I have read through similar questions, and every time it ends up being that the 'ReadLine' statement is used twice. In my case however, I don't.

Can anybody spot why my code only starts at the second line?

I have tried a 'do while' statement, but I don't have the knowledge to execute the code without errors.

```
private void cqaifilesel_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Qtefile;
        Qtefile = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"data\Quote\" + QcomBox.SelectedItem + @"\" + cqaifilesel.SelectedItem;
        if (cqaifilesel.Text != "")
        {
            using (StreamReader read = new StreamReader(Qtefile))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = read.ReadLine()) != null)
                {

                    string[] tokens = line.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    foreach (string sx in tokens)
                    {

                        tokens[0] = labelinvnum.Text; tokens[3] = custNametx.Text; tokens[4] = CustNumtx.Text;
                        tokens[5] = CustCartx.Text;

                    }
                    cqaifilesel.Visible = false;
                    cqaifilesel.SendToBack();
                }





            }
        }
        else { }
    }
```

I would like the 'StreamReader' to read my first line, instead of the second line.

Comment: So I guess the entire community is unable to see the cause of my problem?

Comment: I tried a bunch of different approaches, and still I get the same result. Only displays the second line, not the first. Is it perhaps the string[] Tokens = line.? since line is the string read.Readline?